# Finding equations when given new center of a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, circles, functional-equations, systems-of-equations

$y = −x + \sqrt{2}$, $y = −x − \sqrt{2}$, $y = x + \sqrt{2}$, and $y = x − \sqrt{2}$. These equations determine lines, which in turn bound a diamond shaped region in the plane. 
Construct a diamond shaped region in which the circle of radius $1$ centered at 
$(−5, −4)$ sits tangentially. Use the techniques of this section to help. (Order your answers from smallest to largest slope, then from smallest to largest $y$-intercept. Use $x$ as your variable.)
so the answers I got were:

- $\sqrt{2-(x+5)^2} +4$,
- $\sqrt{2-(-x+5)^2}+4$,

$\sqrt{2-(x+5)^2}+4$

$\sqrt{2-(-x+5)^2}+4$

I dont even know if this is right but this is what I got when I tried to include the shifting from the $(0,0)$ center to the $(-5,-4)$ center.

Comment: Your answers should be lines of the form $y = mx + b$...your answers certainly aren't of that form so they're definitely incorrect.

Comment: so I dont include the numbers from the first part of the question or do I?

Comment: Also, since this isn't calculus, the four lines should have slope $\pm 1$ (you could figure that out through calculus--but you must just assume it based on some geometry).

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to use parametric equations--are you allowed to do that or does that sound familiar?

Comment: we've worked with them a little with change in x and change in y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all you need to do is translate each original solution by $(-5, -4)$ (i.e. to the left by $5$ and down by $4$).  If you have a function, $f(x)$, and you want to translate it by $(x_0, y_0)$ then you do the following: $g(x) = f(x - x_0) + y_0$ where $g(x)$ is the translated function.  So that's it--all you need to do is translate each of those functions.  This means *adding* $5$ to $x$ (since you should subtract $-5$) and subtracting $4$ from that:

Here is one of them (*note the necessary parentheses*):

$$
y_1 = -x + \sqrt{2} \rightarrow \text{ translate to the left by } 5 \\
y_{\leftarrow 5} = -(x + 5) + \sqrt{2} \rightarrow \text{ translate down by } 4 \\
y_{\leftarrow 5, \downarrow 4} = \left(-x - 5 + \sqrt{2}\right) - 4 = -x + \sqrt{2} - 9
$$